# Hide file extension on select dropdown (html/css)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a select dropdown which is dynamically populated with ovpn files so it shows, for example, United Kingdom.ovpn

I would like to hide the .ovpn file extension but I haven't been able to using the script below which seems to work on regular html.

The form element:

```
<select class="selectpicker1" name="ovpn-filename" id="ovpn-filename"></select>
```

The script I've used to try and hide the file extension (.ovpn), it's currently attached to a button :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Hide Extension</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str=document.getElementById("ovpn-filename").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(".ovpn"," ");
document.getElementById("ovpn-filename").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery not available?

Comment: are you using ajax call to get dropdown values? if yes, you can use rtrim() in your php code to remove ".ovpn"

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: so what's your problem if you have already tried, have you failed completely or partially what ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'test.ovpn'; alert(str.slice(0, -5));
```

result is "test"
remove last 5 charecters
try this concept....change like u...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Hide Extension</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str=document.getElementById("ovpn-filename").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/.ovpn/g," ");
document.getElementById("ovpn-filename").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>
```

problem is when you use

```
var n=str.replace(".ovpn"," ");
```

it will only replace your 1st occurrence of .ovpn

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with jquery:

```
 <script>
    var optionString = '';  // declare a string to hold all options
    $("#ovpn-filename option").each(function()
    {
        var str=$(this).val(); 
        var n=str.replace(".ovpn"," ");      //remove .ovpn string        
        optionString +=  '<option>'+n+'</option>';  //add back to that option 
    });
    $('#ovpn-filename').html(optionString );  //assign all option html back to select
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like this approach but I'm struggling to make it work. I've amended my question with the script which populates the dropdown options as I think modifying it with the approach you have here will provide the solution but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Add this code in your button click function, first test it simple without on button click